# How must I use cmake so that the "swig plugin" honors the include path

Tags: cmake, swig

I am using cmake 3.8.1 with the FindSWIG und UseSWIG "extensions" for using swig as code generator. The "swig .i" file contains an include statement to a file in a different directory. The important part of my CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
...
find_package (TCL REQUIRED)
if (TCL_FOUND)
set (HAVE_TCL_H 1)
endif (TCL_FOUND)
find_package (SWIG )
if (SWIG_FOUND)
include(${SWIG_USE_FILE})
set (SWIG_FILE /home/steve/cmake_games/src/foo/bar/bar_swig.i)
set_property(SOURCE ${SWIG_FILE} PROPERTY CPLUSPLUS ON) 
swig_add_library (bar_tclext LANGUAGE tcl SOURCES ${SWIG_FILE}) 
include_directories (/home/steve/cmake_games/src/foo/bar /home/steve/cmake_games/src/this/that)
set_target_properties(bar_tclext PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX) 
swig_link_libraries(bar_tclext ${TCL_LIBRARY}) 
endif (SWIG_FOUND)
```

cmake generates make files without a problem. Executing make however leads to the following error message

```
/home/steve/cmake_games/src/foo/bar/bar_swig.i:3: Error: Unable to find 'that.iih'
```

that.iih is located in /home/steve/cmake_games/src/this/that

Looking at the swig call in the generated Makefile I can see that swig is not called with an include path.

You might think that CMakeLists.txt with absolute paths is weird. True! This is the case due to the fact that the CMakeLists.txt are generated by scripts that take advantage of our conventions in directory topology and naming. We want keep enforcing this by generating the CMakeLists.txt as part of the "configure" process.

What do I need to change in the CMakeLists.txt?

Answer (score 0):

you should try to setup `CMAKE_SWIG_FLAGS` in your case something like:

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_SWIG_FLAGS
"-I/home/steve/cmake_games/src/foo/bar"
"-I/home/steve/cmake_games/src/this/that")
```

e.g.: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/cmake/python.cmake#L57

ps: if you have compile definitions you should also pass them to SWIG by hand since you can't say to swig macro to get all the properties of an associated target.

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot. This does not increase my love for the swig macro but it does for stackoverflow and all the helpful people.